# Which Python For Loop is Better?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to store a special character in a variable 'display' and wanted to know which of these two for loops is better?

```
word = input('Enter a word: ')
display = []
for i in word:
  display += [_]

OR

word = input('Enter a word: ')
display = []
for i in range(len(word)):
  display += [_]
```

Comment: You are not defining the variable `_`, but it's meant to be a literal string of an underscore `'_'`, then what you want should be more efficiently achieved with `display = list('_' * len(word))` or `display = ['_'] * len(word)`.

Answer (score 0):

for loop

As you are directly iterating over the characters in the input word using a for-each loop. This is a more Pythonic way of iterating . you don't need to use the len() function to determine the length of the input word as you do in the second for loop.

Instead, the first for loop automatically determines the length of the input word by iterating through it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).